# ADF CopyData Is it possible to have a dynamic Additional Columns that can be nullable?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a configuration table with file names, destination table name (and other configs) to copy data into a SQL table. Sometimes I want the filename in a new column, but not for every files.

Is it possible to have a default value to not generate additional column for some files?

I tried

```
@json(
    if(
        equals(item().AdditionalColumns, null), 
        '{}', 
        item().AdditionalColumns
    )
)
```

But I get this error: The value of property 'additionalColumns' is in unexpected type 'IList`1'.

And

```
@json(
    if(
        equals(item().AdditionalColumns, null), 
        '{[]}', 
        item().AdditionalColumns
    )
)
```

But I get this error: The function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided value '{[]}' cannot be parsed: 'Invalid property identifier character: [. Path '', line 1, position 1

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out.

```
@json(
    if(
        equals(item()?.AdditionalColumns, null), 
        '[]', 
        item()?.AdditionalColumns
    )
)
```